# export mariadb 10 dump to mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is there a way to use mysqldump or something similar to create an all-databases dump from a mariadb 10 server that will import into a mysql 5.5 server flawlessly? Currently I run into some problems with the dump because of mariadb-only features.

Thank You

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `mysqldump --compatible=ansi --all-databases` to export in ansi mode.

Comment: Thanks you saved me a bunch of time debugging this.

Comment: This switch was also required for me going in the opposite direction (dumping from an older mysql database).  I didn't get any errors, just empty dumps, until I added this switch.